# Tomcat crashes while remote debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat, remote-debugging

I want to remote debug a web application, When I try to debug it with the following command

```
>JPDA_OPTS: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n

>catalina.bat jpda start
```

The application gets deployed, but as soon as I try to go to access it using `http://localhost:8000/....`

The tomcat just crashes! (See the snapshot below)

[image]

I am using windows 7, 64 bit OS, my tomcat 7 and java 6 are both 64 bit.

Did anyone faced this kind of problem before? Any pointers to the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Any error in `catalina.out` or `localhost.<date>.log`?

Comment: I'm not sure because I'm not on my work machine, but I think **8000** is your debug port and you should access the server on **8080**.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a crash of you JVM on dt_socket.dll, it seems related to bug id [6713919](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6713919)

- upgrade java
- access JWDP 8000 port
- use HTTP on port 8080

Comment: Just wondering, should'nt the debug port and the http port be the same ? So if I start tomcat externally on debug port 8000 then the remote debugger(eclipse) be listening to the same port?